# Font-awesome showing up as squares

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

I'm trying to get Font-Awesome (v4.7) to work but it's only showing up as squares. I have the fonts folder in the root of my site and the css in a folder called style. I've added the fonts into the fonts directory and I confirmed the font-awesome.css file @font-face has a url of "../fonts/". I'm assuming that's reference is used by the CSS so that it would be correct if the CSS is in a sub folder of the root and then the font is in the root/fonts folder.

The bootstrap glyphicons work and the bootstrap fonts are in the same directory as the font-awesome fonts.

```
<span class="fa fa-refresh">FA</span>
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cloud">glyph</span>
```

If I look at the dev tools I don't see any errors and I can see the font-awesome tag like it should be.

Anyone have any suggestions?

[image]

MasterPage. I don't know why all the expires are there, I inherited this site but I don't think that's part of the problem.

```
<head runat="server">
    <title>Preferential Bidding System</title>
    <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" />
    <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
    <meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
    <meta http-equiv="expires" content="Mon, 01 Jan 1900 1:00:00 GMT" />
    <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <link href="style/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="style/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" type='text/css' />
    <link href="style/layout.css" rel="stylesheet" type='text/css' />    

    <script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-ui-1.10.1.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
```

Comment: Try an absolute path instead

Comment: If you search for `fa-refresh` or `glyphicon-cloud` in the loaded css, is it there?, sometimes the font is there but the icons we are trying to use are not part of the font!

Comment: I'm not sure how to search for what's in loaded css. I opened up the dev tools and searched for glyphicon-cloud and it only found the one reference I had on the page.

Comment: I edited the original post to show the CSS file references.

Comment: To recap, if you look at your root, you see folders **fonts** and **style**, right? And your HTML file is also in the root?

Comment: Are paths to the actual font files correct in the font-awesome css file??

Comment: From what I can see the paths are all correct and yes the fonts and style folders as well as the .aspx pages are in the root.

Answer (score 0):

First of all try using the  syntax as described at Font Awesome's page (meaning `<i>` as opposed to `<span>`):

```
<i class="fa fa-address-book" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

If that doesn't help continue reading:

I've had this happen to me on multiple occasions during the last 2-3 years and it is always one of the following:

a) wrong relative/absolute path
=> lately I am just using the [Font Awesome CDN](http://fontawesome.io/get-started/), which makes this a non-issue

b) typo in my code - sometimes it is easy to miss the obvious

Looking at your code I am leaning towards a) and I would advise you to try the CDN even if there is a reason to not use it in this instance - but it will help you easily test if there is a problem with your path.

On a side note: are you by any chance using Less to compile some additional CSS beforehand? Maybe there is a mixup with an older version of Font Awesome, which is stored and referenced somewhere (and it could be missing icons, which are e.g. v4.7 only)

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I'll look at trying them. We are supposed to use CDN because the site is for an internal locked down computers but for testing it's a good idea. I'm not compiling LESS in this site. Normally I do but this is an inherited site that I'm trying to minimally change and I didn't want to introduce more complexity at the moment but I might have to change that.

Comment: The CDN worked. Question with the path to the fonts. In the font-awesome.css file the URL is "../fonts/", isn't that relative to the CSS file and not the .aspx page? If it's relative to the CSS file then that is correct since the CSS is in the "root/style" folder. If it's relative to the .aspx then it should probably be just "/fonts/". I think I did try "~/fonts/" and that didn't work.

Comment: I think it's relative to .aspx. Have you tried with an absolute aspx path to be sure?

Comment: The element you use has no bearing on the result. The `.fa` class adds the Font and the `.fa-...` class adds the icon as a pseudo-element. You can do this on *any* HTML element which allows pseudo-elements.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly I've had problems with this before so that's why I suggested it but there could have been other factors in play. Normally you can obviously also use h1 etc. - so yes, you are right; and we have also established that that's not the reason at this point

Comment: Did some more work with this today and have determined it has to do with Chrome. I'm using "Version 54.0.2840.99 m (64-bit)". If I debug in Internet Explorer the icons show up as well as Bootstrap's glyphicons show up in both Chrome and IE. I've been researching but so far haven't come up with a fix.

Comment: @Caverman have you tried stopping Adblocker and/or any other plugins you have in Chrome? There was a GitHub FontAwesome issue about Chrome and icons not showing up