# Why Font Awesome icons not showing in page?

Tags: html, icons, font-awesome, cdn

this is the CDN that I trying to use it to get icons:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" integrity="sha512-SfTiTlX6kk+qitfevl/7LibUOeJWlt9rbyDn92a1DqWOw9vWG2MFoays0sgObmWazO5BQPiFucnnEAjpAB+/Sw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer">
```

and this is my code to show the icon:

```
<i class="fa fa-telegram"></i>
```

but it is showing only a square in the page.
What causes such a problem?

Comment: are these in the same file? [seems to work in same file](https://jsfiddle.net/depperm/yq7z0h9k/) do you have other styling?

Comment: @depperm yes. I use these codes in another page and works very well, but in this page no.

Comment: see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40774234/3462319)

Comment: double check that this is the exact code you are using